# Aplicaciones HTML (HTA) y ES6

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, ecmascript-6, sweetalert2

Soy nuevo por aquí y vaya por delante que mis conocimientos sobre el tema del que pregunto no son muy amplios por lo que puede que la pregunta sea una tontería.

Estoy intentando realizar pequeñas aplicaciones web usando HTA, Javascript y HTML. La intención es aprender y al mismo tiempo desarrollar pequeñas aplicaciones para mi uso personal.
Todo lo hago en el lado del cliente, ya que no es mi intención hacer webs ni trabajar en internet. Ya sé que no es lo más correcto pero HTA me permite hacer cosas muy interesantes y vistosas con no mucho esfuerzo.

El problema que tengo es que HTA no me admite elementos del lenguaje JavaScript ES6 como funciones arrow, foreach etc...
De hecho, al cargar JQuery no tengo problemas pero al cargar por ejemplo bootstrap5 o sweetalert2 me aparecen errores de sintaxis,.
He ejecutado un script que encontré en internet y me indica que mi navegador solo admite ES5.1, sin embargo estoy usando Edge.

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal? ¿No es posible utilizar ES6 con HTA?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿HTA? Eso es **H**iper **T**ensión **A**rterial? Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. No se entiende muy bien tu problema, además considera proveer un [mcve] para intentar reproducir el error que tienes. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder. A mí también me apareció eso en google la primera vez que busqué información sobre HTA. Leeré lo que me has indicado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hace bastantes años no realizo las [HTML Applications (HTAs)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ms536496(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)... por el año 2003/2004 en su momento tenias un control del  navegador que no te daban todos. Funcionaba sobre IE, especificamente sobre el mismo porque se ejecutaba el mshta.exe, que renderizaba con el motor de render de IE y levantaba una app de windows. Hoy no se si esta en Windows 10, y ademas creo que tenia problemas de seguridad (no creo que lo hayan actualizado o mantenido)

Por esa razon **hoy no puedes crear HTAs compatible con lo ultimos motores de renderizado como Chrome, etc que soportan ES6**, porque era algo exlusivo sobre IE.

Para poder seguir con la misma idea se crearon los frameworks que nos ayudaban a "portar" aplicaciones web (HTML puro) a aplicaciones de escritorio, como son:

- El conocido (Electron (https://www.electronjs.org/))[https://www.electronjs.org/]. Que aqui tenemos los ejemplos de app web realizadas con esto que utilizamos como VSCode, Slack, WhatsApp, etc.
- Pero hay otros como [NW.js (https://nwjs.io/)](https://nwjs.io/)

Existen otras alternativas, pero la idea principal es portar o levantar una app  web como escritorio

Ahora bien, tambien te recomendaria otra alternativa que son las [PWA (Progressive Web Apps o Aplicaciones web progresivas)](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/) (que sin bien son aplicaciones web que se ejecutan en un servidor, pueden instalarse como aplicaciones tanto en dispostivos moviles como en escritorio. Pueden trabajar de manera offline, pueden utilizar "las extensiones" de los navegadores para accesar a componentes del dispositivo (geolocalizacion, etc). O sea tiene las ventaja de programar con HTML5 y ES6. Dale una mirada

Dependiendo de tu funcionalidad, o el objetivo final de la aplicacion y como quieras desplegarla o redistribuirla deberias evaluar estas alternativas.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Pensaba que HTA se ejecutaba con el motor del navegador instalado, en este caso edge pero si como dices sigue usando el motor de IE entonces no hay nada que hacer. Miraré lo que me has comentado de PWA aunque lo veo algo complicado. Después de todo mi problema es que en el ordenador que ejecuto las aplicaciones no puedo instalar nada por eso HTA y javascript era una opción sencilla.